# How to find an exact value on a plot?

Tags: matlab

I have a plot which is drawn from points.

I can identify the coordinates values with the brush tool. However I'd be interested in the specific value of a certain x when y value is 0. With the brush tool I cannot pick it exactly.

Is there a way to have the specific y value for x = 0 approximated from the graph?

Comment: Why from the graph? Whi dont you interpolate the data?

Comment: task for a howework, have to do it from the graph

Comment: If its for homework, I am pretty sure they want you to solve some equation and get the value for x when y=0, or vice-versa.